# How to start Squid after the partition is mounted

Tags: boot, systemd, debian-stretch

My home server is running Squid and it used to start at boot without any trouble.  But nowadays Squid does not automatically start at boot, tho it starts just fine when I log in and do `systemctl start squid`.

I believe the problem is simple, as evidenced by the following extract of the console output during boot:

```
[  OK  ] Mounted /home.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x.
See 'systemctl status squid.service' for details.
...
[  OK  ] Mounted /var/cache.
```

Since my Squid's `cache_dir` is under `/var/cache`, the problem is that systemd tries to start the Squid daemon too early.

How can I tell systemd that it needs to wait for all the local file systems to be mounted before starting the Squid daemon?

Comment: It looks like squid is using an old-style init script instead of a systemd unit. Is that just because Debian maintainers haven't gotten around to providing one? Other distros have had a systemd unit for squid for years. It's much more difficult to get those old-style init scripts to load in the right order.

Comment: It's probably because they haven't gotten around to providing one, but really I have no idea.